# assignment to ‘char’ from ‘char *’ makes integer from pointer without a cast

Tags: c, data-structures, queue

I implemented queue in my code and I'm doing polling in my code.
It's giving warning there. "assignment to ‘char’ from ‘char *’ makes integer from pointer without a cast". Can anybody let me suggest where I'm mistaken.

```
#define QUEUE_SIZE 200
char buffer[100];
char queue[100] ; // queue implementaion 
char Rear = - 1;
char Front = - 1;

/*enqueue start */
  printf("3. code reached here \n");
   if (buffer != NULL)
   {
      if (Rear == QUEUE_SIZE - 1)
          printf("Overflow \n");
    else
    {
        if (Front == - 1)
        Front = 0;
        Rear = Rear + 1;
        queue[Rear] = buffer; // this line having above warning //
```

Comment: `queue[Rear]` is a single character. `buffer` is an array of characters. What are you expecting this to do? FWIW `buffer` will never be `NULL`.

Comment: It's great you define a constant QUEUE_SIZE but then you declare your variable with a different magic value.  That's super confusing.  As you only supplied a snippet I can't tell what you are trying to do.

Comment: Code is formatted poorly so I can't tell if you only mean for  only `Front = 0;` to be executed `if (Front == -1)` or i it's a mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The type of `queue[Rear]` is a `char` and the type of `buffer` is `char [100]`.  If you want to copy the first element it would be:

```
queue[Rear] = *queue;
```

If you want to you copy a range you would use `memcpy()`.  As `queue` and `buffer` are the same size you have to be mindful about buffer overflow:

```
memcpy(&queue[Rear], buffer, sizeof queue - Rear);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
queue[Rear] = buffer;
```

In the above statement, `queue[Rear]` has the type `char`, whereas `buffer` has the type `char *`. As there is no implicit conversion from a `char *` to a `char` in C, the compiler is right to generate that warning.

If the intent was to copy the first character, then the statement would be:

```
queue[Rear] = *buffer;

/* OR */

queue[Rear] = buffer[0];
```

Aside: `buffer != NULL` doesn't make sense because `buffer` is an array, not a pointer. It can not be `NULL`.